# PhotoCapture.CreateAsync() never executed

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm using the HoloLens and Unity and I try to take a photo.

I have the same problem as in this discussion
https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/897/locatable-camera-known-issue-photocapture-createasync-doesnt-start

This code in a MonoBehaviour in Unity :

```
void Start() {
  Debug.LogError("CreateAsync start");
  Debug.LogError(WebCam.Mode);
  Debug.LogError(PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions);
  foreach (Resolution resolution in PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions) {
    Debug.LogError(resolution);
  }
  Debug.LogError("END");
  PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (PhotoCapture captureObject) {
    Debug.LogError("CreateAsync done");
  }
}
```

Print this output :

```
CreateAsync start
None
UnityEngine.Resolution[]
END
```

Here is my "Capabilities" part of the Package.appxmanifest :

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap2:Capability Name="spatialPerception" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
</Capabilities>
```

Here is the "Module information" part of the log :

```
Module information:
Built with Compiler Ver '190023918'
Built from '5.5/release' branch
Version is '5.5.3f1 (4d2f809fd6f3)'
Release build
Application type 'D3D11'
Used 'UWP'

OS 'Windows 10 (10.0.14393)'
```

Do you see my problem ?
Can some other script block the execution ?

Comment: With some breakpoints, I have this error : `Failed to initialize IMediaCapture` when the code reach the line : `PhotoCapture.CreateAsync()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the hololens :

`Settings/Privacy/Camera/"Let apps use my camera" => ON`

It's works...
I wish there was an explict error message in this case.