# How to capture video from web camera using unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, webcam, video-capture, hololens

I am trying to capture video from web camera using unity and hololens.
I found this example on the unity page [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.WebCam.VideoCapture.html) .
I am pasting the code below. The light on the cam turns on, however it doesnt record.
The `VideoCapture.CreateAsync` doesnt create a VideoCapture. So the delegate there is never executed.
I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519326/photocapture-createasync-never-executed), however that was on. On the player settings the webcam and microphone capabilities are on.
What could be the problem?

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WebCam;

public class VideoCaptureExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    static readonly float MaxRecordingTime = 5.0f;

    VideoCapture m_VideoCapture = null;
    float m_stopRecordingTimer = float.MaxValue;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartVideoCaptureTest();

        Debug.Log("Start");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (m_VideoCapture == null || !m_VideoCapture.IsRecording)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Time.time > m_stopRecordingTimer)
        {
            m_VideoCapture.StopRecordingAsync(OnStoppedRecordingVideo);
        }
    }

    void StartVideoCaptureTest()
    {
        Resolution cameraResolution = VideoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
        Debug.Log(cameraResolution);

        float cameraFramerate = VideoCapture.GetSupportedFrameRatesForResolution(cameraResolution).OrderByDescending((fps) => fps).First();
        Debug.Log(cameraFramerate);


        VideoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (VideoCapture videoCapture)
        {
            Debug.Log("NULL");
            if (videoCapture != null)
            {
                m_VideoCapture = videoCapture;
                Debug.Log("Created VideoCapture Instance!");

                CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();
                cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
                cameraParameters.frameRate = cameraFramerate;
                cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
                cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
                cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

                m_VideoCapture.StartVideoModeAsync(cameraParameters,
                    VideoCapture.AudioState.ApplicationAndMicAudio,
                    OnStartedVideoCaptureMode);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Failed to create VideoCapture Instance!");
            }
        });

    }

    void OnStartedVideoCaptureMode(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Started Video Capture Mode!");
        string timeStamp = Time.time.ToString().Replace(".", "").Replace(":", "");
        string filename = string.Format("TestVideo_{0}.mp4", timeStamp);
        string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename);
        filepath = filepath.Replace("/", @"\");
        m_VideoCapture.StartRecordingAsync(filepath, OnStartedRecordingVideo);
    }

    void OnStoppedVideoCaptureMode(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Stopped Video Capture Mode!");
    }

    void OnStartedRecordingVideo(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Started Recording Video!");
        m_stopRecordingTimer = Time.time + MaxRecordingTime;
    }

    void OnStoppedRecordingVideo(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Stopped Recording Video!");
        m_VideoCapture.StopVideoModeAsync(OnStoppedVideoCaptureMode);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The problem was that the API doesnt work on the Emulator

Answer (score 1):

You should try taking a look at this thread [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/locatable-camera-in-unity). Where it goes into detail on how to record a video with HoloLens as well as how to take a photo. Also make sure you have the WebCam and microphone capabilities set. Also if you are trying to save it, make sure you have the Videos Library capability as well.

OnVideoCaptureCreated:

```c#
void OnVideoCaptureCreated (VideoCapture videoCapture)
{
   if (videoCapture != null)
   {
       m_VideoCapture = videoCapture;

       Resolution cameraResolution = VideoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
       float cameraFramerate = VideoCapture.GetSupportedFrameRatesForResolution(cameraResolution).OrderByDescending((fps) => fps).First();

       CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();
       cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
       cameraParameters.frameRate = cameraFramerate;
       cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
       cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
       cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

       m_VideoCapture.StartVideoModeAsync(cameraParameters,
                                           VideoCapture.AudioState.None,
                                           OnStartedVideoCaptureMode);
   }
   else
   {
       Debug.LogError("Failed to create VideoCapture Instance!");
   }
}
```

OnStartVideoCaptureMode:

```c#
void OnStartedVideoCaptureMode(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
{
   if (result.success)
   {
       string filename = string.Format("MyVideo_{0}.mp4", Time.time);
       string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename);

       m_VideoCapture.StartRecordingAsync(filepath, OnStartedRecordingVideo);
   }
}
```

OnStartRecordingVideo:

```c#
void OnStartedRecordingVideo(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
{
   Debug.Log("Started Recording Video!");
   // We will stop the video from recording via other input such as a timer or a tap, etc.
}
```

StopRecordingVideo:

```c#
// The user has indicated to stop recording
void StopRecordingVideo()
{
   m_VideoCapture.StopRecordingAsync(OnStoppedRecordingVideo);
}
```

OnStopRecordingVideo:

```c#
void OnStoppedRecordingVideo(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
{
   Debug.Log("Stopped Recording Video!");
   m_VideoCapture.StopVideoModeAsync(OnStoppedVideoCaptureMode);
}

void OnStoppedVideoCaptureMode(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
{
   m_VideoCapture.Dispose();
   m_VideoCapture = null;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work either. It does never create the videoCaptured.
Perhaps I am doing something wrong running it? How should i run it?

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions from the link?

Comment: Yes. As far as I can see `VideoCapture.SupportedResolutions` returns 0 resolutions. Why can that be? Under Edit-Project Settings-Quality I have set it to Very low for UWP

Comment: If you are returning 0 resolutions, you need to make sure that the WebCam Capability is set in the Player settings.

Comment: It is set. I am using a hololens emulator. Perhaps the emulator cannot access the camera?

Comment: @CristianC. Does your computer have a web cam? I am not sure if it works on the emulator.

Comment: The HoloLens emulator doesn't access to WebCamera. But you can try it in the Unity Editor which can access the WebCam.

Comment: Well, offcourse. It turns out the camera doesnt work in the emulator. 
 [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/hololens-known-issues)

Comment: @sGambolati The problem that i have described happens on the editor.