# Unity3D 2019.3.0b7 Recording VideoCapture.CreateAsync does not call the Callback Function

Tags: unity-game-engine, webcam, video-capture, webcam-capture

I'm trying to Record footage from a webcam, but when I try to initialize the Webcam and call the VideoCapture.CreateAsync function my supplied Callback gets never called.

I've tried to access the Camera using a WebCamTexture which works fine.

My StartFunction Looks like this:

```
    VideoCapture.CreateAsync(OnCaptureCreate);
```

My OnCaptureCreate Function looks like this:

```
    void OnCaptureCreate(VideoCapture videoC) {}
```

The Function is the same as in the unity documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Windows.WebCam.VideoCapture.html.

I've Already found this thread [How to capture video from web camera using unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065374/how-to-capture-video-from-web-camera-using-unity) but it only focuses on hololens and I'm trying to record using VideoCapture from the 'UnityEngine.Windows.WebCam' Namespace.

Has anyone had the same problem as I'm having?

Comment: As you're using a beta version of unity it maybe a quirk of that.  Does it do the same on a production level one?

Comment: I have the same problem in 2019.2.10f1.

Comment: The unity doc you link seems to have working example of recording normal webcam.. please share your code

Comment: Its exactly like in the example except for the delegate where i used a function.

Comment: Does it work from the unity docs if you use their code exactly?

Comment: no it doesent work, to test it in 2019.2.10f1 i used exactly the code from the unity docs.

Comment: For Everybody with a similar issue this is is a Reproduced bug in unity. https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/onvideocaptureresourcecreatedcallback-does-not-get-called-when-passing-it-as-a-videocapture-dot-createasync-parameter